# BigDecimal to allows null values

Tags: java, collections, bigdecimal

Looking for BigDecimal library which allows null values in BigDecimal?

Null should NOT be treated as 0 for mathematical purpose.

```
public abc{
  private BigDecimal amount;
   getter();
   setter();...
}
Class main{
if(tempStr == null) {                   
    abc.setAmt(new BigDecimal(" "));
}else if (tempStr != null && !tempStr.equals(" ")) {
      abc.setAmt(new BigDecimal(tempStr));  
}}
```

Amount should allow null values or Blank.
Amount should also accept zero and other numbers.

I am getting amt as zero instead of null or blank

Comment: 1) Why don't you want to use *null* values? Why don't you use *setAmt(null)*? 2) You say it should be not treated as 0. What would you expect from operations like *add()* or *multiply()*? And what would expect from *min()* and *max()* where one of sides is equivalent to your BigDecimal(" ")?

Comment: If you don't want zero for null, why are you writing your code so as to yield it? And what exactly is the meaning of your non-compiling code?

Comment: What is the difference in your model between `null` and `"blank"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java *null* is used to represent undefined values. In your example, this would look as follows:

```
if(tempStr == null) {                   
    abc.setAmt(null);
} ...
```

If you want to check if the string is not empty, you can look at some utililes like Apache Commons StringUtils:

```
if(StringUtils.isBlank(tempStr)) {                   
    abc.setAmt(null);
} ...
```

If you want to avoid explicit *null* values, you may want to consider *Optional<BigDecimal>*. But it is a matter of taste.

Comment: One should not rely on a third party library for something that is trivially achievable with plain Java SE.  `if (tempStr == null || tempStr.isBlank())` will do the job just fine.  (Replace tempStr.isBlank() with `tempStr.trim().isEmpty()` if using a version of Java older than 11.)

Comment: @VGR: For a homework is such library not necessary. But if you have an application with 300 000 lines of code and hundreds places where such check is needed, then the uniformness and readability of the code can be very important. And using a library helps in such case. In your approach there are 3 operations; one needs time to understand what does it mean. Where as when one sees *isBlank(...)*, it can be much easier to understand. But to big extent it is a matter of taste and I will not discuss it further :)

Comment: I do not believe anyone on earth has trouble understanding `if (tempStr == null || tempStr.isBlank())`.  And you are ignoring the heavy penalty incurred by depending on a third party library:  Now the code is less portable, because it cannot be used without also having that library present.  And most third party libraries are poor quality code and have poor documentation, which increases the cost of using them.  Java SE and Java EE have undergone extensive QA and an extensive unit testing suite; look up “Java TCK” for details.

Comment: @VGR: I'd suggest we continue discussion in a chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210462/room-for-mentallurg-and-vgr.

Comment: @VGR: There is an update in the chat.